# "nonL value in assignment " error C++ sorting a linked list

Tags: sorting, compiler-errors, linked-list

Hey guys Im attempting to sort a linked list and having trouble with this error I dont understand wondering if yall can help..the error is only occuring in the 3 lines WITHIN my if statement...Ive labeled them below.

```
void MovieInventory::sortInventory()
{

MovieNode *first;
MovieNode *second;
MovieNode *temp;
    Movie m;
first = movieList;

while (first != NULL)
{
    second = first->next;
    while (second!=NULL)
    {
        if (first->m.getSku() < second->m.getSku() )
                {
            temp->m.getSku()=first->m.getSku(); //error 
            first->m.getSku()=second->m.getSku(); //error
            second->m.getSku()=temp->m.getSku(); //error
            delete temp;
                }
        second = second->next;
    }
    first = first->next;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An L-Value is something where you can assign a value to. In your example you cannot assign a value to the return value of the `m.getSku()` call, this is what the compiler complains about.

I believe you meant to write something like this instead:

```
if (first->m.getSku() < second->m.getSku() )
            {
        temp->m.setSku(first->m.getSku());
        first->m.setSku(second->m.getSku());
        second->m.setSku(temp->m.getSku());
        delete temp;
            }
```

That of course depends on your definition of `Movie` though.